# Import multiple tables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import-from-excel

I need to import many tables (.xlsx format) in MATLAB. I hence tried to do so with a for loop.

The code is reported below:

```
addpath('C:\...'); % here hide the actual path just for simplicity
numfiles = 50;
mydata = cell(1, numfiles);
for k = 1:numfiles
  myfilename = sprintf('Table_%d.xlsx', k);
  mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);
end
```

Even if this actually works it raises problems as duration (hh:mm:ss) and UTCdate arrays are either converted in simple double or NaN.

Can anyone suggest a way around this that solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried [`xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)? I think it can deal with dates properly

Comment: It seems like your problem doesn't have anything to do with multiple files; that part is working.   You should put the conversion issue into the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely use the [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) functionality available in the newer versions of Matlab. This creates a matlab table object which should work for what you need.

The option ('DatetimeType','Text') should help you address your time problem (by writing custom code to handle your date format).

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd rather use the`xlsread` function. It specifically targets Excel files, hence saving some time compared to `readtable` or `importdata`. You can use it in the following way:

Imagine you create a .xls file that looks like this:

```
First     Second    Third
    1          2        3
    4          5     x    
01:43:00       8        9
```

Reading those files with `xlsread` will output three matrices in total.

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx')

num =
     1     2     3
     4     5   NaN
   NaN     8     9

txt = 
   'First'    'Second'    'Third'
   ''         ''          ''     
   ''         ''          'x'    
   '01:43:00' ''          ''    

raw = 
    'First'    'Second'    'Third'
    [    1]    [     2]    [    3]
    [    4]    [     5]    'x'    
   '01:43:00'  [     8]    [    9]
```

You can customize the import in many different ways, applying filters, ignoring certain data structures etc. I recommend you going through the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) for `xlsread`.